# Solve for x and find an approximate value

Tags: linear-algebra, roots

$15 =  \dfrac{((x+3)+(2x-3))h}{2}$
h = $(2x-3) -(x+3) $

& it is also given that $\sqrt{19}$ = 4.36

How can I simplify this & can you help me by explaining the steps

Comment: Use :$$(a-b)(a+b)=a^2 -b^2$$

Answer (score 2):

$$15 =  \dfrac{\left((x+3)+(2x-3)\right)h}{2}=\frac12 ((x+3)+(2x-3))\times((2x-3) -(x+3))=\frac12((2x-3)^2-(x+3)^2)=\frac12(3 x^2-18 x)$$ So, you need to solve $$30=3x^2-18x$$ I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: What do you call these kind of equations? and the method used to solve them? :)

Comment: Quadratic equations $ax^2+bx+c=0$. I am sure that you learn $\Delta=b^2-4ac$ or how to complete the square.

Comment: Is DC 7.6 cm , Correct?

Answer (score 1):

$$30 = ((2x-3)+(x+3))((2x-3)-(x+3))=(2x-3)^2-(x+3)^2=3x^2-18x$$
$$x^2-6x=10$$
$$x^2-6x+9=19$$
$$x=3\pm\sqrt {19}$$

Comment: What do you call these kind of equations? and the method used to solve them? :)